# Tracking which computer printed a document on Windows 2003 domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log, audit, print-server

Currently, when a user prints a document there is an Event ID 10 recorded in our event log. We have mostly XP Clients on a Win2003 domian. However, I cannot tell which computer this user printed a document from. How can I track which computer a user used to print a particular document? If possible, a free solution would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PaperCut - Print Logger](http://www.papercut.com/products/free_software/print_logger/) does exactly what you're looking for and is free [as in beer].  You install it on the print server.  Very light-weight service, very simple interface, generates logs in HTML and CSV.  Logs give you printer name, user name, doc name, pages, copies, duplex, etc, etc...

We used to use a home-brew solution to generate print usage graphs. PaperCut allows us to just slurp the CSV into SQL and do all the graphing magic on the other end.

Comment: I noticed on the screenshot that PaperCut doesn't seem to show which computer a user used. It seems like it shows essentially what the event log shows but I need to know which computer was specifically used in addition the user name.

Comment: @testguy Not sure which screenshot you mean. The log files [both CSV and HTML] most certainly include the computer's name -- The column labled "client" is the computer name from which the print job originated. The column "user" lists the logged on user that sent the print job.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry, I glanced at the pic and assumed client referred to username. The pic I saw is on the PaperCut link you showed. Thanks!